# Xpath query not working

Tags: php, xpath

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="blogEntry expecting featured featured-post-today%e2%80%99s-top-story first">
<h2><a href="/2013/09/03/rachel-zoe-pregnant-expecting-second-child/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child">Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="blogEntry expecting featured featured-post-today%e2%80%99s-top-story first">
<h2><a href="someurl" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child">sometitle</a></h2>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the anchor value. Here is my XPATH:

```
$finder->query('//div[@class="blogEntry"]//h2//a');
```

It's returning no value. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains) here:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<div class="blogEntry expecting featured featured-post-today%e2%80%99s-top-story first">
<h2><a href="/2013/09/03/rachel-zoe-pregnant-expecting-second-child/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child">Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child</a></h2>
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($xml);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($selector->query('//div[contains(@class,"blogEntry")]/h2/a/text()') as $item) {
    echo $item->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Rachel Zoe Expecting Second Child
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay!!

Here is what you are looking for :-

```
//div[contains(@class,"blogEntry")]/h2/a/text()
```

**output**

```
Rachel Zoe Expecting Second Child
sometitle
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I chose the other because it was more complete although your answer was the exact same.